# read only property for checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, html

Is there a read only property for a checkbox?
Because I can still tick on the checkbox even if I have this code, is the read only property only for text box? What's the code if you want the check box to be read-only?

```
<td><input name="stats1" type="checkbox" id="SSS" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $row["STAT"]; ?>" <?php echo $row["STAT"] ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> >SSS</td>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `readonly` attribute on HTML input elements actually means that the **value** is readonly.

You actually want to make a checkbox uncheckable, in that case grab Javascript:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false;">
```

Comment: Since js is ultimately unreliable, though, make sure you check on the backend.

Comment: True, that also applies on `readonly` attribute. One can always disable it using JS or tamper the request parameters. Always, always, always check at serverside, regardless of the input flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Try `disabled="disabled"` instead ;)

Comment: That works, but this way the value won't be sent to the server anymore. That's the difference with `readonly`.

Comment: It would matter in for example requestbased confirmation screens or previews.

Comment: You can avoid that problem by creating a hidden INPUT that represents the value that you want sent back to the server.

Answer (score -1):

here i have inserted 7 checkboxes and set their name as c1,c2....c7 in the html page

```
<input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="english" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="hindi" />
 <input type="checkbox" name="c3" value="gujarati" />
 .
 .
 .
 <input type="checkbox" name="c7" value="Marathi" /> 

 here we will use for loop with upto 7 times iteration 

  for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++)
{
    echo $_GET['c'.$i] ."</br>";    
}


here 'echo' statement will print values from gettig name of checkboxes c1 ...c7

Here $_GET['c'.$i] will print only its value if that checkboox is checked
```